# Android: WebView: Change HTML requested by Submit (GET)

Tags: java, android, form-submit, android-webview

I have a website loaded in WebView on Android 1.6 and I want to get the HTML-Code of a Site which was generated when the user hits Submit. The parameter get submitted by GET, if that's important.
Then I want to change the HTML-Code and show it to the user, without showing the real Answer-page first.

Maybe I could use onFormResubmission() from WebViewClient? But I really have no idea how.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with `WebView`'s API, because you cannot "get the HTML-Code of a Site" that was retrieved by `WebView`. You are welcome to perform your own HTTP operations using HttpClient and feed the results to `WebView` via `loadData()` or `loadDataWithBaseURL()`.